# Preventing jquery background image sprite animation on nav item when hovering over sub-menu

Tags: jquery, css, animation, navigation

I have the following script which handles the animation of a background image for items in my navigation bar:

```
$j(function() {
   $j(".menu-item").find(".bottom_nav").hover(function () {
      $j(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 35px'}
      , 300); }
   , function () {
      $j(this).animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 0px'}
      , 600); }
   ); 
});
```

This works fine, except that when the nav item has a submenu and the user hovers over the submenu I don't want the second animation in this function to fire, i.e. I would like the backgroundPosition to remain as '0px 35px'.  This would work as is, but the submenu is outside  of .bottom_nav div.  The structure of the markup for the menu/submenu is handled by a Wordpress theme and I'm not sure how to alter this.  Here's a screenshot that will give you an idea of the markup:

[image]

As you can see `<ul class="sub-menu">` is outside of the .bottom_nav div.

You can see the nav item in action on [this page](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk).  The second item in the navigation bar called "News" has a drop-down submenu, and I would like the background colour on the nav item "News" to stay green when hovering over this submenu.

Comment: Makes it easier to help if you make a fiddle to work with instead of just linking to the site. This is messy but it does demo the code: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bVxf6/ I think you probably want a `mouseenter/mouseleave` on the parent `li` that surrounds your submenu elements.

Comment: @Jared Thanks, I have set up a simpler jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/bjajy/10/), where I used the setting of the background color rather than any animation.  I would like the background color of #bottom to stay orange, even when hovering over the submenu

Comment: Maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bjajy/11/

Comment: @Jared That's not quite what I was looking for, but thanks anyway.  I think I have it fixed with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/bjajy/12/). Not sure if it is the most elegant solution though!

Comment: The easiest way to handle it is to construct your markup where the highlighted parent element encases the child submenu. Your last fiddle doesn't seem to work in FF (the submenu elements don't highlight?). Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/bjajy/14/ Note, those first two `hover`s could also be combined with a `$.is()` or `$.not()` test to determine what to do.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I don't actually need the submenu elements to highlight for my implementation, which you can now see working [here](http://soteriabrighton.co.uk) on the news item.  Thanks also for the tip about combining hovers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorted this by adding the following:

```
$j(function() {
   $j(".sub-menu").hover(function () {
      $j(this).closest('.menu-item').find(".bottom_nav").stop().animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 35px'}
      , 300); }
   , function () {
      $j(this).closest('.menu-item').find(".bottom_nav").stop().animate( {
         backgroundPosition : '0px 0px'}
      , 600); }
   ); 
});
```